# Prettier term for 'Gastronomic Tolerence'

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

My friend came up with this one, are there any alternatives?

> "Someone who tolerates all kinds of eating habits"

(for example, both vegetarians and non-vegetarians)

Example of sentence: "Tim believes in [term-for-the-above]"

**EDIT:**
Sorry, if I wasn't clear, but my question was not someone who eats variety of food of both plant and animal origin, It was someone who doesn't mind if people around him eat food of various origins. (I'm sure you've met vegetarians who cannot bear to sit on the same table as someone who eats chicken...)

Comment: He is *easy-going*.

Comment: He's not a "foodist".

Answer (score 1):

All of the responders understood "gastronomic tolerance" to mean the ability of an individual to tolerate things that they themselves have eaten.

This suggests that this phrase will not be a useful one, for conveying the concept intended by you and your friend.

"tolerant of other's dietary choices" is wordier but conveys the intended meaning.  If I come up with something pithier, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

***[Foodways](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foodways)*** is a term that you can use  to refer to:

> - the eating habits and culinary practices of a people, region, or historical period.

(M-W)

Comment: Just a heads-up. The OP edited his question.

Answer (score 0):

The medical community uses terms such as "dietary restriction", "dietary avoidance", and "dietary selectivity" to refer to being picky about your food. You can play off this to get antonyms.

- **dietary inclusion**
- **dietary allowance**
- **dietary exploration**